# NPE from org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest when @Test(groups = {"integration"}) through TestNG

Tags: jersey, testng

I have a gradle project that brings in Jersey 2.13, does testing through TestNG, and leverages the Jersey Test Framework.  Any test I run as a plain-jane Unit Test through the @Test annotation runs fine.  If I try to put the Jersey Tests into a TestNG group via @Test(groups = {"integration"}), the tests fail with a NPE coming from org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.  Tests NOT leveraging the Jersey Test framework don't have this problem correctly executing as part of @Test(groups = {"integration"}).  Any ideas why TestNG can't get this container properly started when under groups constraints?

Here is the operative parts of the project...

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.13'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.13'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.13'
    ...        
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.8'
    testCompile 'org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:2.13'
    testCompile 'org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers:jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty:2.13'
}

test {
    useTestNG() { excludeGroups 'integration' }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test, dependsOn: 'test') {
    useTestNG() { includeGroups 'integration' }
}
```

The failing integration tests...

```
public class JerseyTestNGTest extends JerseyTestNg.ContainerPerClassTest {
  @Path("hello")
  public static class HelloResource {
    @GET
    public String getHello() { return "Hello World!"; }
  }

  @Override
  protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(HelloResource.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void notIntegrationTest() {
    // works like a champ...
    doIt();
  }

  @Test(groups = {"integration"})
  public void integrationTest() {
    // NPEs out the wazoo
    doIt();
  }

  private void doIt() {
    final String hello = target("hello").request().get(String.class);
    assertEquals("Hello World!", hello);
  }
}
```

The trail of tears...

```
$ gradle integrationTest
...
:integrationTest

Gradle test > jerseywtf.JerseyTestNGTest.integrationTest FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException at JerseyTestNGTest.java:29

2 tests completed, 1 failed
:integrationTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':integrationTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/robert.kuhar/work/jerseywtf/build/reports/tests/index.html
...    
BUILD FAILED
```

The actual stacktrace...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.target(JerseyTest.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.target(JerseyTest.java:580)
    at jerseywtf.JerseyTestNGTest.doIt(JerseyTestNGTest.java:29)
    at jerseywtf.JerseyTestNGTest.integrationTest(JerseyTestNGTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What's up with that?

The whole project is on github, if you're at all interested in seeing it run, or fail as the case may be:  https://github.com/robertkuhar/JerseyWTF

Comment: Crickets?  Does anyone use the JerseyTest framework?  Maybe thats where I made my mistake.  In any event, this is feeling like a JerseyTest bug, so I filed a ticket:  https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2699

Comment: I have the same problem, but using maven. This seems to be really a bug.

Comment: I have the same problem when I run my jar with the test from command line. When I run from eclipse: no problem... I don't use gradle nor maven